# "No suitable columns" in tabulary

Tags: tables, tabulary, ieeeaccess

There's a `No suitable columns` warning in my `tabulary` table.

I googled a lot, but it seems former examples of this warning were triggered by other things (e.g. `cases`) in the table (e.g. [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/306945/no-suitable-columns-error-when-putting-cases-in-tabulary)).

However, my table is very simple:

```
\begin{table*}
    \centering
    \caption{Experiment Results}
    \begin{threeparttable}
        \begin{tabulary}{.5\linewidth}{l|c||l|c}
            \toprule
            A & B & C & D \\
            \midrule
            E & F & G & H \\
            I & J & K & L \\
             & & M & N\\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabulary}
        \begin{tablenotes}
            \item [*] XXX
            \item [*] YYY
        \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
    \label{tab:res}
\end{table*}
```

Anything I can do to solve such warning?

---

Working exmaple:

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabulary}

\begin{document}


\history{Date of publication xxxx 00, 0000, date of current version xxxx 00, 0000.}
\doi{10.1109/ACCESS.2017.DOI}

\title{FooFooFoo}


\author{Foo}

\markboth
{Author \headeretal: Preparation of Papers for IEEE TRANSACTIONS and JOURNALS}
{Author \headeretal: Preparation of Papers for IEEE TRANSACTIONS and JOURNALS}

\corresp{Corresponding author: First A. Author (e-mail: author@ boulder.nist.gov).}



\begin{abstract}
foo
\end{abstract}

\begin{keywords}
foo
\end{keywords}



\titlepgskip=-15pt
\maketitle

\begin{table*}
    \centering
    \caption{Experiment Results}
    \begin{threeparttable}
        \begin{tabulary}{.5\linewidth}{l|c||l|c}
            \toprule
            AAAAAAA & BBBBBBBB & CCCCCC & DDDDDDDD \\
            \midrule
            Eaaaa & Faaaa & Gaaaa & Haaaaa \\
            Iaa & aaaaaaJ & Kaaaaa & Laaaaa \\
             & & Maaaaaaa & Naaaaaaaa\\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabulary}
        \begin{tablenotes}
            \item [*] XXX
            \item [*] YYY
        \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
    \label{tab:res}
\end{table*}

\EOD

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why you use `tabulary`? From code fragment (please, extend it to complete small document) can't be concluded why is needed.  Please, also replace dummy table content to more realistic contents, which mimic real table. For example, `\begin{tabulary}{.5\linewidth}{l|C||l|C}
\toprule
A & B   & C & D   \\
\midrule
E & FFF & G & HHHHHH   \\
I & JJJ & K & LLLLLL   \\
  &   & M & N   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabulary}` doesn't give any warnings.

Comment: @Zarko Working example added.

Comment: Testing your MWE doesn't give any warnings. However, I got six warnings regarding to used fonts (it may be, that my LaTeX installation doesn't support them). Also `subcaption is not compatible with `ieeeaccess` document class. Try tu use `subfig` package instead (see example of use in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/557146/)

Comment: You are using the `tabulary` environment but not using the columns defined in that package. If I add an `L` column (instead of `l`), the warning is gone.

Comment: The `tabulary` environment is to use at least one L,R, C or J column. The warning, translated for human beings, simply mean: "But what the hell are you doing?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tabulary` determines the widths of `L`, `C`, `R` and `J` columns to achieve the specified table width. If none of these special column types is used in the table, the package can do nothing useful and gives the `no suitable columns` warning.

Probably you want to change `{l|c||l|c}` to `{L|C||L|C}`